# STL sort going into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, stl, quicksort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
#define PR(x) cout << #x " = " << x << "\n";


struct bomb
{
    int x,  y, state;
    bomb(){
        state = 1;
    }
};

bool cmpX(const bomb a,const bomb b){

    if(a.x == b.x){
        int t1 = a.y<0?(-a.y):a.y;
        int t2 = b.y<0?(-b.y):b.y;
        printf("%d %d\n",t1,t2 ); // to check this func
        if(t1>t2) return false;
        else return true;

    }
    int t1 = a.x<0?(-a.x):a.x;
    int t2 = b.x<0?(-b.x):b.x;
    printf("%d %d\n",t1,t2 ); // to check this func
        if(t1>t2) return false;
        else return true;

}


int main(){
    int n;

    cin>>n;
    bomb s[100000];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&s[i].x, &s[i].y);
    }
    sort(s,s+n,cmpX);
}
```

This code is going into an infinite loop on the following input:
    24
    -2 -2
    -1 1
    0 1
    1 1
    0 2
    1 -1
    2 -2
    1 -2
    -1 0
    0 -2
    0 -1
    -2 0
    -2 -1
    2 -1
    2 2
    -1 -2
    -2 1
    2 0
    -1 2
    1 2
    -1 -1
    1 0
    2 1
    -2 2

Following is the ideone link:
http://ideone.com/x1Gbah

Comment: I suggest using `std::tie` or `std::make_pair` to get strict weak ordering.

Comment: BTW: You don't want to copy the arguments for each comparison, use `const bomb&` for the parameters of `cmpX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a strict weak ordering, which mean you need to return `false` if the elements are identical. To fix this, change

```
if(t1>t2)
```

to

```
if(t1>=t2)
```

Comment: Doesn't _strict_ mean `>` as opposed to `>=`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Basically yes, `>` (or `<`) are examples of a strict weak order, `>=` and `<=` not. It also mean that if `a<b` and `b<c`, then `a<c` and if `a<b` is true, then `b<a` is false. And it mean that `x<x` is always false.

Comment: Then your answer `change > to >=` contadicts your explanation, and your own phrase `you need to return false if the elements are identical`. The original OP's code implements correct ordering.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Why? It's the condition to return false. If they compare equal, you must return false. Note that cmpX is the strict weak order operator here!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it's `return t1 >= t2`.

Comment: ...Or replace the entirety of `if(t1>t2) return false; else return true;` with `return t1 < t2;`

Comment: @DrewDormann Ideally yes, but I tried to change as few things as possible to put the focus on the mistake in the thinking that lead to the problem.